# How to count number of unique records of a field in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: field, progress-4gl, openedge

I have customer table with a field age . How can I count how many distinct ages are there ?

Comment: can you give me more detail?

Comment: Under age field , lets say it has values 23,24,23,24,25. So distinct ages are 23,24 and 25 , so count = 3 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in ABL using a FOR-loop and BREAK BY and a counter. 
There are also built in aggregate functions (ACCUM) in the ABL but they are rarely seen in the wild...

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH record NO-LOCK BREAK BY record.age:
    IF LAST-OF(record.age) THEN DO:
        i = i + 1.
    END.
END.
MESSAGE "There are " i " unique ages" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Or by the crippled built in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT age) FROM record.
```

Comment: This is giving me the count of each distinct records 23- 2  24-2 25-1 , I need to get count of distinct records that is count of ( 23,24,25) = 3

Comment: Hi , if I have two  fields ,field1   field2 with data
a          x
a     y
b          z
c          x
c          x
d          y
c          y
a          z        
How can I count the occurence of data for field2 based on field1 , like how many times x has repeated for a , y for a , z for a , and so on for b

Comment: You can use BREAK BY field1 BY field2 and FIRST-OF(field1) or  FIRST-OF(field2) or a combination. You need to read up on basic FOR statements.

Answer (score 0):

It will be somewhat on these lines:
Replace City with age and employee with customer in the following code.

```
def var i as int no-undo.

for each employee break by city:
   if first-of (city) and  last-of(city)
   then do:

      i = i + 1.
   end.
end.
```

display "The count of unique records" i with frame a.